# Populate datatable inside rowexpansion in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a parent list and child lsit. child list is contained inside each parent object so i want to display parent list in a datatable and want to display child list in row expansion in primefaces.but it is not working please help me.the code i am using is mentioned below.

```
<p:dataTable var="loc" value="#{configurationDetailsVo.jointBatchMasterList}" rendered="#{configurationDetailsVo.admissionBatchVo.searchJointBatchPanel}">
                            <p:column style="width:16px">
                                <p:rowToggler />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{message['Academic.JointBatchName']}">
                                <h:outputText value="#{loc.jointBatchName}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{message['Academics.remarks']}">
                                <h:outputText value="#{loc.remarks}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:rowExpansion>
                             <p:dataTable var="jointBatch" value="#{loc.batchList}">
                               <p:column headerText="#{message['Academics.batch']}">
                                <h:outputText value="#{jointBatch.batchName}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{message['Academics.remarks']}">
                                <h:outputText value="#{jointBatch.remarks}" />
                            </p:column>
                               </p:dataTable>
                          </p:rowExpansion>
        </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? What are you seeing vs what do you want to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the rendered often solidifies the page what it makes that `p:rowExpansion` does not work.